# How do I fit a Kernel Density Plot in my histogram using sklearn?

Tags: python, data-science, kernel-density

I'm trying to put a kernel density plot in my histogram but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
n, bins, _ = ax.hist(df[column], bins=num_bins)
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian').fit(n[:,None])
data = np.exp(kde.score_samples(n[:,None]))
ax.plot(bins[:len(bins) - 1], data)
```

My histogram looks like this. I can't get the Kernel Density plot.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Seaborn [function `sns.distplot(df[column])`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) to automatically get a histogram and a kernel density estimate. Seaborn also [has a `kde` plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html): `sns.kdeplot(df[column])`. These do not require you to generate your own kernel density estimate.